# Preserve order of array elements after join

Tags: postgresql, cte, array, recursive

I have a query that returns a CTE looking like

```
+-----------+-------------+
|   node_id | ancestors   |
|-----------+-------------|
|         1 | []          |
|         2 | []          |
|         3 | [1]         |
|         4 | [2]         |
|         5 | [4, 2]      |
+-----------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is join with the `nodes` table and replace the ids that are in the `ancestors` column with another column on the `nodes` table. Here's my query so far:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  -- snip --
)
SELECT node.entity_id AS id,
       array_remove(array_agg(parent_nodes.entity_id), NULL) AS ancestors
FROM tree
JOIN entity.nodes AS node ON node.id = tree.node_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity.nodes AS parent_nodes ON parent_nodes.id = ANY(tree.ancestors)
GROUP BY node.id;
```

The problem with that query is that is loses the order of the original `ancestors` array. Is there a way to perform the join while keeping the original order during the `array_agg` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your query is the join condition `id = ANY(ancestors)`. Not only does it not preserve original order, it also eliminates duplicate elements in the array. (An `id` could match 10 elements in `ancestors`, it would still be picked once only.) Not sure if the logic of your query would allow duplicate elements, but if it does I am pretty sure you want to preserve all instances - you want to keep "original order" after all.

Assuming current Postgres **9.4+** for lack of information, I suggest a completely different approach:

```
SELECT n.entity_id, p.ancestors
FROM   tree t
JOIN   nodes n ON n.id = t.node_id
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT p.entity_id
      FROM   unnest(t.ancestors) WITH ORDINALITY a(id, ord)
      JOIN   entity.nodes p USING (id)
      ORDER  BY ord
      ) AS ancestors
   ) p ON true;
```

You query only works as intended if `nodes.id` is defined as primary key and `nodes.entity_id` is unique as well. Information is missing in the question.

Normally, this simpler query without explicit `ORDER BY` works as well, but there are no guarantees (Postgres **9.3+**)...

```
SELECT n.entity_id, p.ancestors
FROM   tree t
JOIN   nodes n ON n.id = t.node_id
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT p.entity_id
      FROM   unnest(t.ancestors) id
      JOIN   entity.nodes p USING (id)
      ) AS ancestors
   ) p ON true;
```

You can make this safe as well. Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f9e1e/4) for Postgres 9.3.

#### Opional optimization

You join to `entity.nodes` twice - to substitute for `node_id` and `ancestors` alike. An alternative would be to fold both into one array or one set and join only *once*. Might be faster, but you have to test.
For these alternatives we *need* the `ORDER BY` in any case:

Add `node_id` to the `ancestors` array before we unnest ...

```
SELECT p.arr[1] AS entity_id, p.arr[2:2147483647] AS ancestors
FROM   tree t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT p.entity_id
      FROM   unnest(t.node_id || t.ancestors) WITH ORDINALITY a(id, ord)
      JOIN   entity.nodes p USING (id)
      ORDER  BY ord
      ) AS arr
   ) p ON true;
```

Or add `node_id` to the unnested elements of `ancestors` before we join ...

```
SELECT p.arr[1] AS entity_id, p.arr[2:2147483647] AS ancestors
FROM   tree t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT p.entity_id
      FROM  (
         SELECT t.node_id AS id, 0 AS ord
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM unnest(t.ancestors) WITH ORDINALITY
         ) x
      JOIN   entity.nodes p USING (id)
      ORDER  BY ord
      ) AS arr
   ) p ON true;
```

You did not show our CTE, this might be optimized further ...

Comment: I actually ended up doing the join in the CTE, but I tried this out and it worked as well! I think this solution may become the more performant solution once there are more rows in my DB.